# Skip given file types from replacing special charactors of the URL in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, rules

I have added some rules in the .htaccess file in order to add some rules. One of those rules are replacing special characters like the sample below,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)û(.*)$ /path/$1u$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\s(.*)$ /path/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)&(.*)$ /path/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /path/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)%(.*)$ /path/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

I want this rule not to apply if the request URL is having .js, .css or any other given extension.

I tried couple of solutions but still no luck. Here are some of the codes suggested in similar problems,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
```

Appreciate if anyone can help?

This was an important point from Ranil

> Remember, Each RewriteCond condition only applies to the immediately
>   following RewriteRule. That means if you have a bunch of rules, you
>   have to duplicate the conditions. If you really don't want to do that
>   for some reason, you could use a negate at the very beginning of all
>   your rules

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a another rewrite condition to exclude the requests with the specific file names.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css)$`

The above condition will validate for the specific file types and make it fasle.

The full code will be

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)û(.*)$ /path/$1u$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\s(.*)$ /path/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)&(.*)$ /path/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /path/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)%(.*)$ /path/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

You may use online tool like http://htaccess.mwl.be/ for the debugging.

Comment: Thanks, The testing tool is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)û(.*)$ /path/$1u$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\s(.*)$ /path/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)&(.*)$ /path/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /path/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)%(.*)$ /path/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Remember,

Each RewriteCond condition only applies to the immediately following RewriteRule. That means if you have a bunch of rules, you have to duplicate the conditions. If you really don't want to do that for some reason, you could use a negate at the very beginning of all your rules

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RedirectMatch (.*)\.js$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1.js
RedirectMatch (.*)\.css$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1.css
RewriteRule ^(.*)û(.*)$ /path/$1u$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\s(.*)$ /path/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)&(.*)$ /path/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /path/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)%(.*)$ /path/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```